# Android: How to Change to Text Size in ListView become bigger?

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, android-linearlayout

I am blurred with the situation below where I create a LinearLayout to display contact list from my phone. But, I can't figout out where I can actually set the text inside LinearLayout to become bigger!Please help, thanks!!!!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/contactList"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:padding="10dp"
              android:textSize="200sp"
              android:layout_weight="10"/>
    <CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/showInvisible"
              android:text="@string/showInvisible"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/addContactButton"
            android:text="@string/addContactButtonLabel"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The contactmanager.xml as below:

```
package com.example.android.contactmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public final class ContactManager extends Activity
{

    public static final String TAG = "ContactManager";

    private Button mAddAccountButton;
    private ListView mContactList;
    private boolean mShowInvisible;
    //public BooleanObservable ShowInvisible = new BooleanObservable(false);
    private CheckBox mShowInvisibleControl;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created. Responsible for initializing the UI.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "Activity State: onCreate()");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact_manager);

        ArrayAdapter<String> filesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
        R.layout.simplest_list_item_1, topFilesArray);
        filesList.setDivider(null);

        // Obtain handles to UI objects
        mAddAccountButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addContactButton);
        mContactList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactList);
        mShowInvisibleControl = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.showInvisible);

        // Initialise class properties
        mShowInvisible = false;
        mShowInvisibleControl.setChecked(mShowInvisible);

        // Register handler for UI elements
        mAddAccountButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "mAddAccountButton clicked");
                launchContactAdder();
            }
        });
        mShowInvisibleControl.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Log.d(TAG, "mShowInvisibleControl changed: " + isChecked);
                mShowInvisible = isChecked;
                populateContactList();
            }
        });

        // Populate the contact list
        populateContactList();
    }

    /**
     * Populate the contact list based on account currently selected in the account spinner.
     */
    private void populateContactList() {
        // Build adapter with contact entries
        Cursor cursor = getContacts();
        String[] fields = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME
        };
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_entry, cursor,
                fields, new int[] {R.id.contactEntryText});
        mContactList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    /**
     * Obtains the contact list for the currently selected account.
     *
     * @return A cursor for for accessing the contact list.
     */
    private Cursor getContacts()
    {
        // Run query
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
        };
        String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '" + (mShowInvisible ? "0" : "1") + "'";
        //String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '" + (mShowInvisible.get() ? "0" : "1") + "'";
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

        return this.managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    }

    /**
     * Launches the ContactAdder activity to add a new contact to the selected account.
     */
    protected void launchContactAdder() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ContactAdder.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }


}
```

The contact_entry.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:text="@+id/contactEntryText"
              android:id="@+id/contactEntryText"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Which layout item are you using for each element?

Comment: Post your item layout xml file. Otherwise, increase the size of your textView in your item layout's xml file simply. It will give bigger size text in your `ListView`

Comment: @Praveen, how i gonna to code in the texView size? android:textsize=10?

Comment: +1 yes. That's it.. How many layouts are you using??

Comment: Show us your **R.layout.contact_entry** layout

Comment: Thanks to @Praveen and IGP, my problem is solved!!!!!!Thanks..being 1st time here, i can't imagine how fast you guys can help me and go thru with my problem!!!Thanks!!!!!

Comment: btw, how i can make those contact_entry into button, so that when user click on that, it can show up the contact person details...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set this property `android:textSize="10dip"` of Textview into contact_entry.xml, it will solve your problem.

Comment: after creating, the line android:textSize="10" saying as below:
error: Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'textSize' with value 
 '10').

Comment: may i ask u a silly question again? I am new to android and i do have a contactmanager.java which use contactmanager.xml as now, so how i gonna to add in ur simplest_list_item_1.xml ?

Comment: @SeanTan Your Question's XML code is from contactmanager.xml file?

Comment: yes, it's from the contactmanager.xml, do i need to insert ur code inside that?

Comment: @SeanTan No don't put this code into your xml file, make separate xml file.

Comment: IGP: Can u give me some clue about how to make those contact entry into functionable button? means user can click on that on will be prompted that contact ppl details...

Answer (score 0):

it is always better to set the size of text in sp (Sp is scaled independently with respect to the normal font size of the device. ) or you can use `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge`