# change size of text of item of list view in .java

Tags: java, android

I have one activity **(main.xml & main.java)** and an extra **item.xml** file to define the item of list, the main.xml contain listView and its java file is main.java. So the question is how to change text size of listItem in main.java ?
if main.xml contain a text(eg. t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);), we can change it by writing:

```
t.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,16);
```

But how to change text size of **item.xml** in main.java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TextView - setting the text size programmatically doesn't seem to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998938/textview-setting-the-text-size-programmatically-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to Change to Text Size in ListView become bigger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643389/android-how-to-change-to-text-size-in-listview-become-bigger)

Comment: do you want to change the size of 'TextView' dynamically/with any event?

Comment: are you using an adapter?

Comment: i don't want to change dynamically...i want to set it manually..and ya i am using adapter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are using an adapter. Override the getView() method inside the adapter and inside this:

```
TextView text = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,16);
```

In case you don't understand, I'm attaching below, a sample overriden getView() method inside the adapter.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if(listItemView == null)
    {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    EarthQuake currentEarthQuakeObj = getItem(position);

    TextView magText = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.magnitude);
    magText.setText(Double.toString(currentEarthQuakeObj.getMagnitude()));

    return listItemView;
}
```

Comment: Keep your sample as small and clean as possible. All these details distract from the solution.

Comment: thanx for help...! why i am getting nullpointer when i use Sharedpreference for the value of size:

Comment: thanx for help...! why i am getting nullpointer when i use Sharedpreference for the value of size:
    TextView mode = (TextView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.modeId);
        mode.setText(currentinfo.getMode());

        mode.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,sharedp.getInt("font_size",18));

m getting nullpointer exception.

Comment: I don't have knowledge in SharedPreferences... So I can't help... sorry

Comment: no no its k...i declared the Sharedpreference but forgot to initialize...sorry..now ma app working fine..thanks lot